# map python list of months to values

Tags: python-3.5

I have 2 lists whereby the sequence of values in the second list map to the months in the first list:

```
['Apr-16', 'Jul-16', 'Dec-15', 'Sep-16', 'Aug-16', 'Feb-16', 'Mar-16', 'Jan-16', 'May-16', 'Jun-16', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15']
[15, 15, 6, 81, 60, 36, 6, 18, 36, 27, 24, 29]
```

I need to retain 2 seperate lists for use in another function.  Using python how do I achieve sorting the lists into monthly order whilst retaining the existing mapping of values to months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to

- associate both lists
- sort the resulting list of couples according to the year/month criteria (months must be converted as month indexes first using an auxiliary dictionary)
- then separate the list of couples back to 2 lists, but now sorted according to date.

Here's a commented code which does what you want, maybe not the most compact or academic but works and is simple enough.

```
a = ['Apr-16', 'Jul-16', 'Dec-15', 'Sep-16', 'Aug-16', 'Feb-16', 'Mar-16', 'Jan-16', 'May-16', 'Jun-16', 'Oct-15', 'Nov-15']
b = [15, 15, 6, 81, 60, 36, 6, 18, 36, 27, 24, 29]

# create a dictionary key=month, value=month index
m = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
monthdict = dict(zip(m,range(len(m))))

# the sort function: returns sort key as (year as integer,month index)
def date_sort(d):
    month,year = d[0].split("-")
    return int(year),monthdict[month]

# zip both lists together and apply sort
t = sorted(zip(a,b),key=date_sort)

# unzip lists
asort = [e[0] for e in t]
bsort = [e[1] for e in t]

print(asort)
print(bsort)
```

result:

```
['Oct-15', 'Nov-15', 'Dec-15', 'Jan-16', 'Feb-16', 'Mar-16', 'Apr-16', 'May-16', 'Jun-16', 'Jul-16', 'Aug-16', 'Sep-16']
[24, 29, 6, 18, 36, 6, 15, 36, 27, 15, 60, 81]
```